# Django - fresh database and no such table

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm using my complex jobs app in production and it works fine, with sqlite database. I'm trying to create new database from scratch and I cannot do that nor using migrations nor trying to make them once again:

When I'm trying to reuse my migrations:

```
rm db.sqlite3
python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/backend/server/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/backend/server/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/backend/server/jobs/admin.py", line 57, in <module>
    class TagCategoryDefaultImportanceAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
  File "/backend/server/jobs/admin.py", line 59, in TagCategoryDefaultImportanceAdmin
    extra = len(Role.objects.all())
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1303, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: jobs_role
```

When I've tried to remove all migration files:

```
  mv jobs/migrations jobs/old_migrations
  rm -Rf db.sqlite3
  python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/backend/server/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/backend/server/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/backend/server/jobs/admin.py", line 57, in <module>
    class TagCategoryDefaultImportanceAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
  File "/backend/server/jobs/admin.py", line 59, in TagCategoryDefaultImportanceAdmin
    extra = len(Role.objects.all())
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1303, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/backend/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: jobs_role
```

How can I investigate what is going on? Where is the problem with jobs_role table?

It figures out, that problem is related to my admin.py file

```
class TagCategoryDefaultImportanceAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TagCategoryDefaultImportance
    extra = len(Role.objects.all())
    max_num = len(Role.objects.all())
    formset = TagCategoryDefaultImportanceAdminFormse
```

The `extra` and `max_num` fields cause the issue. How can I handle that in a correct manner?

Comment: Is that the entire traceback? At first sight it looks like you have some python file (models, views, etc.) that runs a query when you start the server, and thus does not do that when the server is ready to start. For example something like `Role.objects.all()`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no It was not the entire traceback. I've just paste the entire one.

Comment: as the error says, you have an `extra = len(Role.objects.all())` that is thus evaluated *eagerly*, before `makemigrations`, `migrate`, `runserver`, etc. even really start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates:

```
File "/backend/server/jobs/admin.py", line 59, in TagCategoryDefaultImportanceAdmin
    extra = len(Role.objects.all())
```

This meansthat when *interpreting* the file, it will already run this query. This is thus also the case if the database is not (yet) fully migrated, hence the error.

As a (strong) rule of thumb, you should try to avoid running queries when *interpreting* the file (reading the file into memory), since these will thus run *before* the server starts running, and before the database might be properly set up. Even if that would work, it would mean that `extra` takes as value the number if items when you *start* the server: if you would later add/remove a role, then `extra` would not change.

Usually you should try to wrap the logic into a function such that it only will evaluate `Role.objects.all()` when it *runs* the function, and such admin functions are then typically only triggered when the user visits the admin pages.

As for this specific case, you can use the [**`.get_extra(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.get_extra) and [**`.get_max_num(…)`** methods <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.get_extra):

```
class TagCategoryDefaultImportanceAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TagCategoryDefaultImportance
    formset = TagCategoryDefaultImportanceAdminFormset
    
    def get_max_num(request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return Role.objects.count()
    
    def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return Role.objects.count()
```

Comment: You are right, that problem is caused by admin.py file. I've got the admin.TabularInline model with field: extra = len(Role.objects.all()).

How can I rearrange this extra field to make it working? Putting it in a standalone function will be sufficient?

Comment: @SmallJoe: please edit the quesiton with the part of the code where you use this.